# ListView items outside initial view aren't clickable

Tags: android, listview, scroll, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I have four ListViews which I synchronize their scrolling in order to scroll simultaneously when either of them is scrolled. The first ListView is filled by a custom adapter and contains only a TextView and the rest three are filled by another custom adapter and contain a RatingBar. Both adapters extend ArrayAdapter.

Here's the problem:

Whenever I scroll one of them, although the scrolling process is smooth and in sync, the items outside the initial View don't behave properly.
I cannot click on them. I get a null pointer exception.
They get the data located in the initial View.
[image: problem illustration]

- green get same data
- red are not interactive

I believe that it has something to do with the getView() when I scroll. The fields don't get populated correctly. Isn't getView() supposed to be called when a ListView is scrolled?

Comment: Would grid view not do what you need better?

Comment: I load each ListView with different data from a database. Each one has its own adapter.